# Installing Wine on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, wine, 15.10

I'm trying to install Wine on my PC running Ubuntu 15.10, but I see in the software center there are different apps such as:

- [Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine/) with some optional addons
- [Wine Windows Program Loader](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/wine1.4/)
- [Wine tricks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/winetricks/)
- [q4Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/q4wine/)

I have tried installing via the terminal, but after trying to use the final command which is `/sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks`, I get an error message that says something like broken or incomplete, and also something  about amd64 and i386.

Any help would be appreciated, I had wine before but I thought it was giving my Ubuntu PC problems, possibly because I have a Windows 10 PC and it was trying to communicate with my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_in_English

Comment: Reformat your question, repair your CapsLock key and add the whole error message if you need an answer. I understand nothing. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Wine is available for Ubuntu 15.10 (also called wily).

1. To download simply open your terminal and type the following.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   ```

and wine will be installed on your system. The above command will itself download all the dependencies required.

Winetricks comes with the wine package; installing wine will install it too.

**Points to be noted**

1. Using `sudo apt-get install wine` will install the stable version of wine, which I think is wine-1.6.2
2. Now, if you still want wine 1.7, which is unstable, then you will have to add the wine PPA. The information on how to do so can be found in [installing wine 1.7](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/128-desktops/805164-wine-1735-released-how-to-install-on-ubuntudebianlinux-mint)
3. If you try to run `sudo apt-get install wine1.7` without adding the PPA, you will see some errors.
4. After adding the PPA, you will be able to run `sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks` too (most probably).

Comment: when I entered "sudo apt-get install wine" I got following result E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it? .What can be done  now???

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Answer (score 2):

Run PlayOnLinux instead.  It will install Wine1.7 if it is required for a program.  It runs side-by-side with Wine.

To do this:

Open a terminal and enter the following

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Once it is done installing open terminal again (if it is not already), and enter:

```
PlayOnLinux
```

Optional: Once it opens right click its icon and **Lock to Launcher**.

Follow the steps, read the dialogs, and enjoy.

Comment: when I entered "sudo apt-get install PlayOnLinux" I got following result       E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
.Can you help me what to do now???

Comment: That is because you are currently updating/installing software elsewhere in the system.  In that scenario just wait for the other software to finish installing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multiarch support. It's trying to download `wine-i386`

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```