# How to install Wine in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wine, winetricks

I tried to follow the steps listed here https://www.linux.com/blog/wine-1735-released-how-install-ubuntudebianlinux-mint

After adding the PPA and running `apt-get update`, when I try to install wine with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
          Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also read this: [Installing Wine on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701694/installing-wine-on-ubuntu-15-10), but nothing seems to help.

Also, (I don't know if I should mention this in another question or if it is related to the current error I get) I had installed winetricks and it worked without any problem after installing "playonlinux" (I don't know if the problem started BECAUSE I installed playonlinux since I didn't use winetricks for days prior to trying to install playonlinux so the underlying problem may or may not have been created prior to this installation) I couldn't find winetricks on my apps list and right clicking on .exe files would pop winetrickes on "Open with" option...

Last but not least, in `/usr/bin/` there is no winetricks executable, only a winetricks shell script.

Comment: BTW, Winetricks is a shell script.

Comment: Indeed and Winetricks can be updated independently of your Wine installation: http://askubuntu.com/q/755059/57576

Comment: Wine 1.7 was the development release for Wine 1.8. Now Wine 1.8 is released, and you should use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wine 1.7 not installing on Xubuntu 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689034/wine-1-7-not-installing-on-xubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu:

If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install (example for the development branch):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

If you prefer to use the devel (not Staging) branch, replace `winehq-staging` with `winehq-devel` in the line above.

If apt-get complains about missing dependencies, install them, then repeat the last two steps (update and install).

To install the latest version of Winetricks (recommended, the version in the repos is old), run:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks && sudo cp winetricks /usr/bin/ && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/winetricks
```

Comment: well I dont know how to install the missing dependencies since from what i can gather (im a newbie :P ) the missing dependency is the package I want to intall in the frist place

Comment: this is the ouput when I try to install winehq-devel:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 1.9.7~ubuntu15.10.1)

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel wine-devel`

Comment: run      sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel wine-devel  but it ouputs  "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel : Depends: wine-devel-i386 (= 1.9.7~ubuntu15.10.1)
" so I run      sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel wine-devel-i386 but it outputs "The following packages have unmet dependencies:wine-devel-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed" and when trying to run sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel libsound2-plugins it outputs "E: Unable to locate package libsound2-plugins"

Comment: I suppose libsound2 belongs to a different repository but something tells me that even if installing it again an other problem will arise... 15.10 is such a fail it has so many dead ends and incompatibilities sometimes  not even things that run on 15.04 can run on 15.10.... I should have installed  the  14.04 version... poor me didnt get why there wasnt a 15.10 LTS version... now I know...

Comment: It said libasound, then you tried libsound.

Comment: yea the question is how... google doesnt show up anything about that except a repository which I have add and tried to apt update/upgrade but nothing I searched some more and find out that these libasound2 plugins are part of ALSA library additional plugins but I have that already installed according to my software center...   but I dont know whats up since according to my software center I have winetricks installed as well... yet I cant find it anywhere....

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel libasound2-plugins:i386`

Comment: Did that command work?

Comment: " but I dont know whats up since according to my software center I have winetricks installed as well... yet I cant find it anywhere...."  The winetricks menu entry does not always show up in the menu, just run it in the terminal.

Comment: Did you run the first command in the answer? (`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`)

Comment: Sorry I was AFK well  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel libasound2-plugins:i386 did run and installed quite a bunch of things (also can you tell me how you insert code form in the comments? :P ) so after that when I tried to run  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel the output is that winehq is already its newest version.... but when I try to run sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7 I get the same exact output as I did in the first place (look at OP)

Comment: Once `winehq-devel` is installed, you do not need `wine1.7` installed, as `winehq-devel` installs the latest version of Wine.  BTW, use backticks around code for the formatting.

Comment: To confirm that Wine is installed, run `wine --version` in the terminal.

Comment: it sais that wine 1.9.7 is installed  (but I want 1.7 since thats compatible with the exe I want to install through wine) playonlinux sees when click on "use an other version of wine" pops only 1.5 as an available option..

Comment: also I noticed that playonlinux ALSO (along with winetricks) doesnt appear in my apps list anymore no matter that in software center when I click on it displays it as installed.. (it does the same for winetricks... ) how can that be? do the commands mentioned in this post unistall packages needed for this programs to work?

Comment: Any applications that work on 1.7 should also work on 1.9.  You could try reinstalling POL and Winetricks using the Software Center to make the menu entries appear again.  Note that I recommend running the last command in the answer to update Winetricks after reinstalling, as the version in the Software Center is **VERY OLD**.